# Invalid file or folder characters - OneDrive

Tags: macos, finder, software-recommendation, high-sierra, filesystem

I'm looking for some help, I'm trying to help a user migrate from Dropbox to OneDrive, However, I've found that OneDrive doesn't support some of the file names that she has within Dropbox. Which are part of the invalid filenames unsupported by OneDrive ( **~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | }** ).

There are around 400 conflict items, which are in a number of different folders/sub-folders. The only methods I've found only appear to either replace the file names of a given selected folder, or require me to drag the conflict items into an application and then replace them. This is all pretty manual as this will require quite some time.

Does any body know of a method which can start searching within a given Finder directory @i.e OneDrive, and then replace any invalid characters no mater their location under the root (one drive) folder?